# Is it possible with Import Activity to clear data extension if salesforce report is empty?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-import

Hi I have created an automation to import data from saleforce report to overwrite data in a data extension. This is working fine when salesforce report is not empty, however, if the report is empty it should clear data in data extension. I use Overwrite as update type in my import activity. Please help how can I achieve this. TIA.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I think, Salesforce can enable this feature for you :)

Answer (score 3):

This indeed is something which is not enabled by default. You will need to ask Salesforce Support to allow allow blank file processing - a setting which is managed by a business rule in the backend of Marketing Cloud.